# How to implement a function that caches / memoizes results of requests in the inner scope

Tags: javascript, caching, promise, scope, closures

Im trying to implement a function to make requests which caches the results.

The requirements are:

- Can't use **any global variable**.
- Results should be stored **in the functions inner scope** using closure.

I cant find any way to store a result inside the functions scope without using a class. I tried the following code but I realized `this.responses` is actually a global variable at `window.responses`. Any way to do it?

```js
function cachedRequest(url) {
    if (!this.responses) this.responses = {} // This is actually a global variable at window.responses, cant use it
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const cachedValue = this.responses[url]
        if (cachedValue) {
            console.log('returning cached result')
            return resolve(cachedValue)
        };
        fetch(url).then(res => {
            console.log('fetching and caching result')
            this.responses[url] = res
            return resolve(res)
        })
    })
}

const URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/"

cachedRequest(URL).then((response) => {
    console.log({response})
    cachedRequest(URL)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a *memoization* function which keeps track inside a closure of which arguments are already used. You can inject each callback in the `memo` function to keep a storage on.

It also enables you to inject any amount of arguments and makes your code very flexible.

```
const memo = (callback) => {
  const cache = new Map();
  return (...args) => {
    const selector = JSON.stringify(args);
    if (cache.has(selector)) return cache.get(selector);
    const value = callback(...args);
    cache.set(selector, value);
    return value;
  };
};

const cachedRequest = memo(fetch);
const URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/";

cachedRequest(URL).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  cachedRequest(URL);
});
```

Comment: With asychronously derived data, it's always better to cache Promise rather than value. Thus, further request(s) for the same data, made before the Promise resolves, can be satisfied by the as yet unsettled Promise.

Comment: That is actually very clever!

Comment: This is really very clever and smart! Used in my project thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `cachedRequest` to itself as the `this` context within the function.

```
cachedRequest = cachedRequest.bind(cachedRequest);
```

The Promises will keep the same context as arrow functions do not create a new  one.

```js
function cachedRequest(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!this.responses) this.responses = {};

        const cachedValue = this.responses[url]
          console.log("function context => ", this.name);
          console.log("this.responses => ", Object.keys(this.responses).length)
        if (cachedValue) {
            console.log('returning cached result')
            return resolve(cachedValue)
        };
        fetch(url).then(res => {
            console.log('fetching and caching result')
            this.responses[url] = res
            return resolve(res)
        })
    })
  
}
cachedRequest = cachedRequest.bind(cachedRequest);

const URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/"

cachedRequest(URL).then((response) => {
    cachedRequest(URL)
    console.log("window.responses =>", window.responses != undefined);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your request function in another function that defines the cache object. The returned function then has access to that object.

```js
function cachedRequest() {
  const cache = {}
  return function(url) { // returned function has access to `cache`
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const cachedValue = cache[url]
      if (cachedValue) {
        console.log('returning cached result')
        return resolve(cachedValue)
      }
      fetch(url).then(res => {
        console.log('fetching and caching result')
        cache[url] = res
        return resolve(res)
      })
    })
  }
}

const URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/'

const request = cachedRequest() // initialize the request caching function

request(URL).then(response => {
  console.log({ response })
  request(URL)
})
```

Comment: With asychronously derived data, it's always better to cache Promise rather than value. Thus, further request(s) for the same data, made before the Promise resolves, can be satisfied by the as yet unsettled Promise.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, Good point. I didn't think about that but it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the module pattern like so:

```
const myApp = (() => {

    let responses = {};

    const cachedRequest = (url) => {
        if (!this.responses) this.responses = {} // This is actually a global variable at window.responses, cant use it
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const cachedValue = this.responses[url]
            if (cachedValue) {
                console.log('returning cached result')
                return resolve(cachedValue)
            };
            fetch(url).then(res => {
                console.log('fetching and caching result')
                this.responses[url] = res
                return resolve(res)
            })
        })
    }

    const init = (url) => {
        cachedRequest(url);
    };

    return {
        init
    }

})();

const URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/";
myApp.init(URL);
```

This way, only init() would be a public method. Everything else is not accessible.

Comment: With asychronously derived data, it's always better to cache Promise rather than value. Thus, further request(s) for the same data, made before the Promise resolves, can be satisfied by the as yet unsettled Promise.